# What are Wonder Woman, the Flash, and Aquaman?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, powers

So, in the *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice*, we have:

- Lex Luthor, a human psychopath
- Batman, a human psychopath  ( :) )
- Cyborg, a apparently a technology enhanced human; i.e. a cyborg
- Superman, an alien
- Doomsday, an alien/human hybrid based on alien (Gen Zod) and human (Lex Luther's) DNA

So what exactly are the other meta-humans we've seen:
- Flash
- Wonder Woman
- Aquaman

Are they aliens, naturally occurring <s>mutant humans</s> uh, I mean meta-humans, altered in some way, or what?

Comment: First, I think it's not appropriate to mix the nolanverse with the DC extended universe. Second, I guess we'll juste have to wait and see...

Comment: What does this have to do with *The Dark Knight* trilogy? It seems your question is just about the DCEU.

Comment: Wonderwoman is not clear, since there's so many different origin stories about her we won't know until the JL film.

Comment: @Kalissar, sorry -- for some reason I didn't realize the Nolanverse and the DCEU were supposed to be different things.   Removing Nolanverse.   Please consider reversing the vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote ! I considered voting to close but I don't remember how we handle "wait and see" questions so I just left a comment.

Comment: I seem to have read in an article that BvS:DoJ's Wonder Woman was like 5000 years old. If they made that explicit in the movie I completely lost it. Whatever plans DC/Warner has for this franchise and its characters are "not yet fully revealed" and more might be "behind the scenes" and "suitable to change according to box office or script needs" than what we can really know for sure at this point, in terms of origins and/or "accuracy with a given comic story"

Comment: If you're asking specific to the DCEU, the future works policy is applicable.

Comment: @phantom42 thanks to the "future works" key words I was able to find the [question I was looking for on meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/13418). I'm voting to close this question as recommended in the linked meta question.

Comment: @phantom42 I don't think so...the question is "what are they?" not "what will be revealed about them?" It's a clear question that is based on and about what we know about them today.

Comment: @Kalissar:   The 'consider reversing vote' can be considered directed at everyone who downvoted based on the (former) inclusion of the Nolanverse.

Comment: @ThePopMachine you neglected to include Doomsday, an alien/human GMO/hybrid based on Gen Zod and Lex Luther's DNA.

Comment: Asking "what are they?" is no different  than "what will be revealed about them?" if there is no/insufficient information currently known. The point of the future works policy is to prevent rampant speculation and partial answers.

Answer (score 9):

In the DC universe, any Earth-born humanoid that is different (i.e., powered) from regular humans is usually called a meta-human. There is nothing to suggest this definition is different in DCEU, the files taken from Lex are labeled META-HUMAN and have the following four characters listed under that heading.

**Wonder Woman** = un-aging clay golem? She is at least 100 years old, and I vaguely recall her making a comment relating to centuries. Before the New 52, she was modeled from clay and had life given to her by the Greek Gods. Since then she is the goddess daughter of Queen Hippolyta and Zeus, king of the Greek Gods. Still born on Earth though.

**Aquaman** = Atlantian, traditionally king/prince of the sea, descended from the survivors of the Lost City of Atlantis.

**Flash** = human turned meta from an accident involving *plot device* + lightning.

**Cyborg** = while his reanimation is a mystery (mother box?) he is typically classified as a meta-human.

Comment: +1, for fixing Wonder Woman part before I can complete my comment ;)

Comment: Cyborg's New 52 origin has him merging with a Mother Box which seems likely for the Snyderverse version given the look of the cube in the video clip and all the Darkseid references.